# TapGestureRecognizer only works in certain places on the screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I inserted in the `CollectionView`, in which one a Grid, a `TapGestureRecognizer`, but I noticed that it works only if I press in some specific points of the `CollectionView` / `Grid`, in some positions the event works, the others not, it is as if the 'button' was smaller than the Grid

**this is my code xaml:**

```
 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                  <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                   </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                       <Frame
                        CornerRadius="5">
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Gainsboro" Margin="-20">
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundClor="LightBlue"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Data}"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="11" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                            <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                 <Label Text="{Binding Nota}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14"/>
                            </ScrollView>
                                    
                        </Grid>
                       </Frame>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to express, could you explain it with some screenshots?

Comment: (https://ibb.co/vjFfNFP)

Comment: Did you try to add the TapGestureRecognizer to the inside grid ?